# Section 33.(2) of the Canadian Charter (ie Notwithstanding Clause)

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

[Source:](http://teacherweb.com/ON/PerthDistrictCollegiateInstitute/CindyRotar/NotwithstandingClause%28Notes%29.pdf) *What is the Notwithstanding Clause?*, by [Cindy Rotar](http://teacherweb.com/ON/PerthDistrictCollegiateInstitute/CindyRotar/t.aspx) BA LLB

> Section 33 contains five clauses. The wording of each clause is as follows:
>   ...
>   (2) An Act or a provision of an Act
>   **[1.] in respect of** which a declaration made
>   under this section   is in effect
>   shall have such operation as it would have
>   ***[2.] but for*** the provision of this Charter referred to in the declaration.

1. Does **in respect of** = for?

2. Does **but for** = without?

3. Is my paraphrase right? For want of separating the clauses, I spaced the text.

> > (2) An Act or a provision of an Act
> >     **FOR** which a declaration made
> >     under this section   applies
> >     shall OPERATE as [the aforesaid Act] would have
> >     ***if*** the provision of this Charter (referred to in the declaration) ***had never been applied***.

Comment: Please don't omit.  Your omissions and visible gaps actually make things harder to read, not easier.

Comment: @TRomano Understood. In actuality, i didn't omit anything; I wrote that caution needlessly. Removed.

Comment: Please quote things *intact*, without embedded annotations at least once.

Answer (score 1):

> An Act or a provision of an Act in respect of which a declaration made
>   under this section is in effect shall have such operation as it would
>   have but for the provision of this Charter referred to in the
>   declaration.

Repunctuated slightly:

> An Act or a provision of an Act (in respect of which a declaration made
>   under this section is in effect) shall have such operation as it would
>   have but for the provision of this Charter referred to in the
>   declaration.

In legal contexts, "but for X" typically means "were it not for X".

**The car would have gone over the cliff *but for* the excellent guard-rail.**
**The car would not have gone over the cliff  *but for* the faulty guard-rail.**

*In respect of which" means "in relation thereto" or "in response thereto" or (loosely) "having the aforementioned in mind".

*Highway guard rails in the Commonwealth have proven to be unreliable; the bolts were not rust-proof. In respect of which, this Act requires the manufacturer to replace those bolts and to pay a fine of $15 million.*